# Submit a parameter in a neo4j algo query

Tags: python, neo4j, parameters

I am running Neo4j 3.4.1.
I ran a clustering algorithm and created clusters with labels 'labelpart'.
Now I want for each cluster find the node with the highest betweenness centrality.
I can run the following query for a specific cluster_id, say 3212

```
CALL algo.betweenness.stream(
  'MATCH (p {labelpart:3212}) RETURN id(p) as id',
  'MATCH (p1 {labelpart:3212})-[]->(p2 {labelpart:3212}) RETURN id(p1) as source, id(p2) as target',
  {graph:'cypher', write: false}
) YIELD nodeId, centrality
RETURN nodeId,centrality order by centrality desc limit 1
```

Now, I want to do it programmatically for all cluster ids. 
I tried the following query using neo4j bolt driver for python:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
```

and here is the query

```
cluster_id = 3212
query = """
CALL algo.betweenness.stream(
  'MATCH (p {labelpart:{cluster_id}}) RETURN id(p) as id',
  'MATCH (p1 {labelpart:{cluster_id}})-[]->(p2 {labelpart:{cluster_id}}) RETURN id(p1) as source, id(p2) as target',
  {graph:'cypher', write: false}
) YIELD nodeId, centrality
RETURN nodeId,centrality order by centrality desc limit 1
"""
results = session.run(query, parameters = {'cluster_id':cluster_id })
```

I get the following error message

```
....
ClientError: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.betweenness.stream`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterNotFoundException: Expected parameter(s): cluster_id
```

Using a parameter works for a simple query, e.g. I can do the following

```
cluster_id = 3212
query1 = """
MATCH (p {labelpart:{cluster_id}}) RETURN id(p) as id
"""
results = session.run(query1, parameters = {'cluster_id':cluster_id })
```

Now, my guess is the problem is that the queries that I need to submit parameters to are themselves parameters of the algo.betweenness.stream() function.

Unfortunately,I couldn't find any directions on how to submit a parameter for such a query. Perhaps it's just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@David, Your guess is correct.

You need to write the query like:

> ```
> query = """ CALL algo.betweenness.stream(   'MATCH (p {labelpart:{cluster_id}}) 
>  RETURN id(p) as id',
>  'MATCH (p1 {labelpart:{cluster_id}})-[]->(p2 {labelpart:{cluster_id}}) RETURN id(p1) 
> as source, id(p2) as target',
> {graph:'cypher', write: false, params:{cluster_id:{ext_parameter_name}}}
> ) YIELD nodeId, centrality RETURN nodeId,centrality order by
> centrality desc limit 1 """
> ```

**ext_parameter_name** is the parameter to session.run.
(Used different name to avoid confusion).